# calculated histogram doesn't look as expected

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas, typescript

I'm trying to implement histogram RGB but my algorithm doesn't produce similarly look like surface as in graphics programs. For example image on this site:

[OpenCV histogram](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)

My version looks like:

[image: RGB Histogram R channel]

As I understood it correctly, RGB Histogram just measuring how often each value occured in specific channel. So I implement it in such way:

```ts
        public Process(layerManager: dl.LayerManager) {
            var surface = layerManager.GetCurrent();
            var components = new Uint8Array(1024);
            surface.ForEachPixel((arr: number[], i: number): void => {
                components[arr[i]] += 1;
                components[arr[i + 1] + 256] += 1;
                components[arr[i + 2] + 512] += 1;
                components[arr[i + 3] + 768] += 1;
            });
            var histogram = layerManager.GetHistogram();
            histogram.Clear();
            var viewPort = layerManager.GetHistogramViewPort();
            viewPort.Clear();
            this.DrawColor(histogram, components, 0, new ut.Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
            //histogram.SetBlendMode(ds.BlendMode.Overlay);
            //this.DrawColor(histogram, components, 256, new ut.Color(0, 255, 0, 255));
            //this.DrawColor(histogram, components, 512, new ut.Color(0, 0, 255, 255));
        }

        private DrawColor(surface: ds.ICanvas, components: Uint8Array, i: number, fillStyle: ut.Color) {
            var point = new ut.Point(0, 255);
            surface.BeginPath();
            surface.FillStyle(fillStyle.R, fillStyle.G, fillStyle.B, fillStyle.A);
            surface.RGBAStrokeStyle(fillStyle.R, fillStyle.G, fillStyle.B, fillStyle.A); 
            surface.LineWidth(1);
            surface.MoveTo(point);
            for (var j = i + 256; i < j; ++i) {
                point = new ut.Point(point.X + 1, 255 - components[i]);
                surface.ContinueLine(point);
            }
            surface.ClosePathAndStroke();

            var viewPort = layerManager.GetHistogramViewPort();
            viewPort.DrawImage(surface.Self<HTMLElement>(), 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, viewPort.Width(), viewPort.Height()); 
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Uint8Array` array to hold the results, but the most common RGB values are occurring more than 255 times. This causes an overflow and you end up seeing a histogram of the values modulo 256, which is effectively random for high values. That's why the left and middle parts of the graph (where values are less than 255) are correct, but the higher-valued areas are all over the place.

Use a larger data type to store the results, and normalize to the size of your output canvas before drawing.